# Where to place common business logic for all pages in symfony2

Tags: symfony, dry

I am now working on my first symfony2 project. I have created a service, and I need to call it for every controllers to generate a html which is necessary throughout the all pages in my website.

So I created a BaseController class which extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller class and tried to place the code in this BaseController class. Now whenever I call from the constructor:

```
$my_service = $this->get('my_service');
```

or

```
$my_service = $this->container->get('my_service');
```

I got error:

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object.
```

The container object has not been initialized. What is the solution to this problem? How DRY method is followed in symfony2, if I want to place left panel or header in all pages which contains dynamic data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you registered that service in your `confil.yml`? It can be done via importing or direction declaration...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use the constructor in your controller class, especially when you inherit from Symfony Controller: that way you get the container **after** the object instantiation (the DIC will call the setContainer method inherited from Symfony's Controller).

In general, for your first experiments, use the services in the action methods; if there is some cross-cutting logic that you need to execute in every request you could consider registering some event listeners (see the "Internals" docs in the Symfony website).

When you get more confidence with the framework you can start thinking about not inheriting Symfony's Controller, registering your controller classes in the DIC and injecting the services that you need manually (eventually implementing some logic in the constructor).

Comment: Thanks Aldo, the event listeners seems the best solution to this problem. I have looked upon it. Looks like I need to make a listener class for event 'GetResponseEvent'. But I am unable to add some variables which will be sent to view for rendering. Can you give me one example code to do this?

Comment: I think that when you intercept the response event the templates have already been evaluated into their string representation (encapsulated in the response object); if I'm right that's not the right place where to inject variables for the view. I would try to use the kernel.request event and attach variables to the request object (you can access them in the view using the app.request.get('attrib') helper). More advanced you can use the kernel.view event and render the templates in your listener attaching eventual variables.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not the answer you desire, but if you need some html on all pages, I think using a service the way you do is the wrong way.

I guess you know about twig and the possibility to use a layout to place common code. But you can also embed a controller:

```
{% render "AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles" %}
```

Within the recentArticlesAction, you can place your specific code and return a template. By this, you can get custom html into each of your templates! See the symfony docs for more: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I just figured it out this way, that I will make a controller for general purpose(say to calculate header or right panel data) and render its actions from view as you did in this example; as I am not using twig, I think this also can be done using php engine.

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted. Above each code example, you can see a switch for different languages. There you can see how to embed a controller into a php template!

Answer (score 0):

Business logic is all the custom code you write for your app that's not specific to the framework (e.g. routing and controllers). Domain classes, Doctrine entities and regular PHP classes that are used as **services** are good examples of business logic. [Ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html)