# Symfony2 common session strategy

Tags: symfony, cookies, dry

I have a symfony2 web project consisting of ten pages which are rendered via 5 controllers. User can land a site through any of the pages above (via shared link for example). And I need to show a welcome popup (just div with `position:absolute`) to users who opens the page for the first time during the current session.

I've already placed my popup in the common twig template which is used by all the pages needed. Now I have to determine whether to show popup or not. I'm going to show popup based on boolean value from controller.

I have to work with session and cookies, but I have to do that on each page and I don't want to write the same code (check and set cookies, output a boolean to show popup in template) in every method of each controller. Is there a way to this according to DRY concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Sgoettschkes answer here [Where to place common business logic for all pages in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669439/where-to-place-common-business-logic-for-all-pages-in-symfony2?rq=1)
I tried this method
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

And it looks awesome:
My Popup is included in the main template like this

`{{ render(controller('MalyutkaMainBundle:WelcomePopup:index')) }}`

Than inside the controller I manipulate session vars

```
class WelcomePopupController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $session = $this->get('session');

        $showWelcomePopup = 0;

        if ($session->has("have_seen_welcome_popup_on")) {
            // tbd compare to the date of publishing of the new popup screen 
        } else {
            $showWelcomePopup = 1;
            $session->set("have_seen_welcome_popup_on", new \DateTime());
        }

        $params = array (   
            'show_welcome_popup' => $showWelcomePopup
        );

        return $this->render('MalyutkaMainBundle:WelcomePopup:welcome_popup.html.twig', $params);
    }
}
```

And nothing is to be added in other controllers - just what I wanted to do.
But it is impossible to change cookies that way, so I store my data in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a wrapper class which handles checking, setting, and getting the current session values and make it a service.

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\My\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class SessionManager /* or whatever you want to call it */
{

  public function __construct(Session $session)
  {
    $this->session = $session;
  }

  public function getMyValue()
  {
    return $this->session->get('my.value.key',null);
  }

  public function setMyValue($value)
  {
    $this->session->set('my.value.key',$value);
    return $this;
  }
  public function hasMyValue()
  {
    return $this->session->has('my.value.key');
  }
}
```

And in your bundle services.yml

```
<service id="mytag.session_manager" class="My\Bundle\My\Namespace\SesionManager">
    <argument type="service" id="session" />
</service>
```

And in your controllers

```
public function someAction()
{
   $sessionManager = $this->get('mytag.session_manager');

  if($sessionManager->hasMyValue())
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```